# WSO2 ESB Error Publishing Event from a MQTT Inbound Endpoints

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

When I try to publish an Event to DAS from a sequence that starts from an mqtt Inbound Endpoint, appears the error described here: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4516 that happens with the Scheduled Task.
I tried this with ESB 4.9 and 5.0 Beta and receive the same error.
There is a way to workaround this?

Comment: Did you apply the fixes in the links? You could do so by finding the appropriate packages, opening them with an archive extractor and replacing the changed files. For example, MessageInjector.java is located in the synapse-core_2.1.3.wso2v11.jar in ESB folder/repository/components/plugins.

Comment: The fix is included at 5.0 Beta, and see that is working with Scheduled Tasks, but is not working with Inbound Endpoints.

Comment: I found the exact error https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4420 and is unresolved. There is a way to know when will be fixed? Thank you.